# Calculating Cumulative Totals and Date that a Certain Threshold is Reached in SQL

Tags: sql, date, percentage, cumulative-sum

I have a simple table with Person, Date and Quantity:

```
Person    Date     Qty
Jim     08/01/16    1
Jim     08/02/16    3
Jim     08/03/16    2
Jim     08/04/16    1
Jim     08/05/16    1
Jim     08/06/16    6
Sheila  08/01/16    1
Sheila  08/02/16    1
Sheila  08/03/16    1
Sheila  08/04/16    1
Sheila  08/05/16    1
Sheila  08/06/16    1
```

I'd like to calculate two columns:  Cumulative Total and Percentage of Total, resulting in the following table:

```
Person    Date    Qty cum tot  pct of tot
Jim     08/01/16   1    1         7%
Jim     08/02/16   3    4        29%
Jim     08/03/16   2    6        43%
Jim     08/04/16   1    7        50%
Jim     08/05/16   1    8        57%
Jim     08/06/16   6   14       100%
Sheila  08/01/16   1    1        17%
Sheila  08/02/16   1    2        33%
Sheila  08/03/16   1    3        50%
Sheila  08/04/16   1    4        67%
Sheila  08/05/16   1    5        83%
Sheila  08/06/16   1    6       100%
```

And with this dataset, I would like to identify the date for each person where their pct of tot reaches 50% (or any other percentage I supply).

So the output for the 50% threshold would be:

```
Jim     08/04/16
Sheila  08/03/16
```

Any suggestions on how I can calculate the two columns and determine the appropriate dates?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANSI standard cumulative sum function to calculate the cumulative sum.  The rest is really just arithmetic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (partition by person order by date) as running_qty,
             sum(qty) over (partition by person) as tot_qty,
             (sum(qty) over (partition by person order by date) * 1.0 / 
              sum(qty) over (partition by person)
             ) as running_percent
      from sales t
     ) t
where running_percent >= 0.5 and
      running_percent - (qty * 1.0 / tot_qty) < 0.5;
```

The reason the `where` clause has two conditions is to return a single row.  The first will return all rows greater than or equal to 0.5, but you only want the first -- where the percent crosses the threshold.

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.

Comment: Gordon, I'm having problems applying your code.  My table is named sales.  I tried changing the FROM statement to reflect the sales table, but still get the following error message:

Comment: Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'qty'.
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The column prefix 'sales' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: @Coding_Newbie . . . All the columns in the subquery have aliases.  `qty` is in your original table.

Comment: I got it now.  Thanks Gordon.